# Wordpress - use of meta data to get postcode and output a google map

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps

I'm trying to use meta data to get a postcode, so something like:

```
$property->add_meta_box( 
    'Property Info', 
    array(
        array(
              'name'        => 'postcode',
              'label'       => 'Postcode',
              'type'        => 'text',
        );
     )
);
```

to create a meta box on every post type - property. How do I use this postcode to get a google map to generate on a page dynamically, IF the property has a postcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show how I did it but this was a year ago and there is perhaps a more updated, modern answer based on updates to Google Maps / Geocoding.  Geocoding being the term for the process of converting a postcode to a Latitude/Longitude.  This code was all in my `single.php` as I was using it to display the map on individual posts, you could do things differently depending on how you've set it up.

I had originally used Yahoo Maps API to geocode a postcode and then use Google Maps for the map as Google Map's geocoding was woefully inaccurate.  Yahoo turned their service off, so I changed it to the Google Local Search version of geocoding which was more accurate at the time than Google Maps (this was last year, 2011).

Firs of all make sure you include the scripts to the map API in your `<head>`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

and

```
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
```

In your template you access your custom option (assuming it has an id of `postcode`) like;

```
<?php $postcode = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postcode', true); ?>
```

And then use the following Javscript to geocode the address and generate your map (in `#map_canvas`).

Here's the JS;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var localSearch;
var map;
var icon;
var addressMarkerOptions;
google.load("search", "1");
google.load("maps", "2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

function initialize()
{

    localSearch = new GlocalSearch();
    icon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
    addressMarkerOptions = { icon:icon , draggable: false};

    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl3D ());
    var mapControl = new GMapTypeControl();
    plotAddress("<?php echo $postcode ?>");

}

/**
* This takes either a postcode or an address string
*
*/
function plotAddress(address)
{
  localSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null, 
function() {

  if (localSearch.results[0])
     {     
    var resultLat = localSearch.results[0].lat;
    var resultLng = localSearch.results[0].lng;
    var point = new GLatLng(resultLat,resultLng);
    var marker = new GMarker(point, addressMarkerOptions);
    map.setCenter(point, 15, G_HYBRID_MAP);
   }
});

localSearch.execute(address + ", UK");
}
</script>
```

The HTML is as follows;

```
<div id="streetview">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 250px; height: 250px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, so where do you use <?php $postcode = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_property_info_postcode', true); ?> in the template? Or doesn't it matter? (I've used a plugin so _property_info_postcode is how I access postcode).

Comment: Put it just prior to the Javascript, or you could call the option directly and insert it into the JS rather than assigning it to a variable.  I just did that to show how to access the custom option and then use it.

Comment: That's where I'm calling it I think, perhaps you could take a look at my code, I seem to be on the right path - http://www.web-want.com/estate/property/19-compton-road/

Comment: Had a look and have updated the answer - I've removed a load of extraneous stuff, plus that site was running on Mootools, I've got rid of anything like that from my answer as it's just a distraction.  To be honest I don't know how relevant this answer is now there's a maps API3.  First of all you've not included the Google Maps js link in your head so it had no chance of working.  You are calling your postcode correctly though! :)

Comment: Do you have to call <body onload="intitalize()"> somewhere as well? I've got an API key now.

Comment: Damn - yes, sorry mate.  <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"> You can see them all here; http://www.dehotun.com/62-west-kilbride/

Comment: Nice one @snakespan, that's great - well done for working it all through despite me missing out key bits in the initial answer!